# count(*) in hibernate criteria?

Tags: hibernate

I have a combination of  search criteria which implemented by using hibernate criteria.
And I added a pagination like this :

```
criteria.setFirstResult(offset).setMaxResults(pageSize).setFetchSize(pageSize).list();
```

This is not enough for a pagination , so I have count the total result size .

```
totalResult = (Integer)criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult();
```

The problem is , the first time I submit the search form , I got correct totalResult.
When I click next page , and the offset changes , I got a NullPointExcetion at second statement . I don't know why . And through debugging , I can see when this exception occurs , the first statement successfully return the paginated results.

So I want to ask , does the first statement conflict the second ? (because the first statement set the fetchsize to 10 , and I wonder if the count(*) function will work properly.
they are different task using same criteria , How can I clone or copy one criteria that already has numerous restrictions been added ?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the conflict is actually the restriction in the count query, so I'd expect it to return wrong results on the second run of the pagination query.

Using a single Criteria for both requires some resetting between uses, which can probably be done along the lines of:

```
 criteria.setProjection(null)
         .setResultTransformer(Criteria.ROOT_ENTITY);
```

If you really want two separate but identical criteria, I think the easiest way is to first create a DetachedCriteria, which is Serializable, and use the serialization-deserialization cloning hack to make another one, before converting them to normal Criteria by attaching to a session.

But if you can work in a reset, you might not need two.

Comment: Thanks , actually my solution is exactly the same with your answers. It works !

Answer (score 33):

Just to fix count(*) query - better use this code for criteria:

```
Integer totalResult = ((Number)criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult()).intValue();
```

otherwise you will get an error `java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer`

Comment: Nice way without cast: `Integer totalCount = criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult().hashCode();`. You will have the same result.

Comment: neat trick! didn't realize this until I saw you comment and looked and jdk source code.

Comment: I'm not sure I trust your neat trick (although I am impressed). The hashCode() contract says that the hash code need not remain the same from one run to the next, so Oracle is totally within its rights to change the hashCode() method, although it's not very likely. Still, I'd rather just call intValue().